# classical and quantum correlation functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

### Quantum Field,   quantum fluctuation even with no temperature

In QFT, the correlation function $<0|\hat{\phi} (x)\hat{\phi} (y)|0>$ describes the fluctuation correlations of vacuum state $|0> $, there is no temperature here.

### Classical Field, correlation is a result of thermo fluctuation

$<\phi (x)\phi (y)>=<(m(x)-\bar{m})  (m(y)-\bar{m})>$

---

But in the end, their math expression looks the same ---- Green function

$\int dp\frac{e^{ipx}}{p^{2}-m^{2}+i\epsilon }$   OR   $ \int dk\frac{e^{ikx}}{k^{2}-(\frac{1}{\xi })^{2}+i\epsilon }$

Even their math methods are same.

1. decoupled modes in momentum space,
2. then Fourier transform back to real space.

---

### My questions are:    What's the physics behind such similarity? And what's the essential difference?